# Getting "'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable" when using max()

Tags: python, typeerror, python-3.5

I'm trying to set up a dictionary that will allow user input for names and corresponding score (adding the game name as well would be a bonus), and then be able to query the highscore.

Here is what I tried:

```
scores = {}

while True:                                                                                                 
    name = input("Please give me the name of the player [q to quit]:")
    if name == 'q':
        break
    else:
        grade = input("Give me their score: ")
        scores[name] = grade

highScore = max(scores.values)

for k, v in scores.items():
    if v == highScore:
        print(v, k)
```

This is the error I got:

```
highScore = max(scores.values)
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 4):

[max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) accepts an iterable, but you passed it a function.

```
print(type(scores.values))   # <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
print(type(scores.values())) # <class 'dict_values'>
```

Just pass the output of the function, not the function itself.

```
highScore = max(scores.values())
```